# ANOVA with non-normal distribution, doubting whether I can apply CLT/what else to do

Tags: anova, normality-assumption, central-limit-theorem

I did an ANOVA to compare the effect of two therapies. Different participants were used for both therapy groups, 25 randomly assigned to each group. I did normality tests for the results after therapy and it was significant for one group. So I was wondering

1) whether I can use the CLT. I was taught that the CLT can be applied when sample sizes are larger than 30. I'm doubting about whether to see my sample size as 25 or as 50.

2) and what to do when I cannot apply the CLT. Transforming the data is not really what the exercise is aiming for. I searched a bit and found that ANOVA is "quite" robuust to the assumption of normality and can be "a little" violated, but I am wondering what this means exactly.

Comment: There is a lot of similar questions on this site, but none seems really like a duplicate ... See if some of the posts in this list can help you:  http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=anova+non-normal